# Unable to login as root user

Tags: ubuntu, login, password, root, failed

[Ubuntu server]

I was able to login to the server just fine for days. And now I cannot login with the root user with password and private key both are not working.

Luckily I am currently logged in as the root user. Basically I logged in as the root user and have been doing stuff for a couple of hours and then I went to another terminal to login with and it just does not work. I get "Permission denied, please try again."

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config i have this set

```
"PermitRootLogin yes".
```

In the authorized_keys I still have my public key set

```
ssh-ed25519 AA...{it's the whole key in they file}...Ddw
```

And since I didn't change anything regarding the login options. The best thing to assume is that someone entered the system. Ok great but now still persists the issue why can't I login because what I did was change the password with

```
passwd root
```

and after the change I try to login but I cannot.

This is the output from ssh -vvv
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDyTJ.png)

Comment: Please check the log files for messages about your login attempts. Running the ssh client with `-vvv` could also be helpful.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've edited the post with the image that is given when running with -vvv, and the log files are a bit messy because the ssh is running on port 22 and it's allowed to use password for login so there is alot of login attempts from china...

Comment: Well, without the log files there is no way to diagnose it. And please, don't post screenshots of text that you could copy&paste. You are just making it harder to extract information out of it.